# Back button functionality not working properly

Tags: android, webview

I have created a webview as overlay over another webview and had doubts regarding the back button implementation of the second webview.My aim is if I click the back button it should come to the first webview. This is my XML page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.app.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"/>
<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/external_webview">
</WebView>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ext_link"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backtonews"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button">
        </Button>
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This the functionality that I wrote for the back button

```
 news.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               exWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Now If I click the back button the back functinality is not working and the contents of the overlay webview (2nd webview) is enlarged as if it is zoomed in. Pleas guide me in my code.Does it contains any mistakes?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I found that If i click the back button it is going to the first webview but it is coming back to the second webview again automatically and it is happening so fast. I found this out by using Toast.

Comment: try writing `news.bringToFront()` right after setOnClick.

Comment: after the function ?

Comment: yes.. try it. or write it as a last line of your onCreate. Try both ways and see if it's working?

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working

Comment: put the breakpoint at the line `exWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`. debug the app and see if its reaching there?

Comment: Yes it is going. But I noticed that it is coming back again to 2nd webview. It is happening so fast as if it never went to 1st webview. Saw the flow using Toast

Comment: now what is the problem?

Comment: I resolved it.  It is because of cache. Set cache as true.

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the back press button clicks then you should Override `onKeyDown`.

Here is an example

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

           //HERE YOU WILL HANDLE THE BACK BUTTON CLICKS

          exWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I have a button in my app itself still should I use this method ?

Comment: No this is for default back button, I thought you trying it for default one, well try it and see if it works there

Comment: I want it for the button that I have placed in the overlay webview. Default back button will quit the app. That's how I have written the functionality.

Comment: no need of doing this. onClick is enough. This will complicate the simple thing.